# Cluster a group of words visually based on the meaning of the word

Tags: r, nlp

For instance- given the words, c(cat, dog, grapes, oranges), I would like to produce a scatterplot with cat and dog clustered together and grapes and oranges clustered together. Is this possible?

Despite numerous searches, I could not find results related to semantic clustering.

Example:

[image]

Comment: `word2vec` can be used to compare similarity in meaning. So can the `BERT` model.  `UMAP` can do multidimensional visualization clustering.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example in order for people to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want your figure to look like without more details or a close example of what you would like. What is the x axis? what is the y axis? Or do you mean a more general [word cloud](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-a-word-cloud-with-r-bde3e7422e8a)?

Comment: @jpsmith I want a more general word cloud but words similar in meaning are clustered together.

Comment: If you have a small corpus, you will need to rely on pre-trained word embeddings, eg from the `textdata` package. https://smltar.com/embeddings.html#glove

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.